# Cloning a django project from hg using buildout and using it for development

Tags: django, mercurial, buildout

I have a django project sitting in a bitbucket repository. Is it possible to automate using buildout, the following process:
1. Install django
2. clone the django project from hg repository
3. install the dependency modules of the django project

**Update:** I have achieved what I wanted to, with the help of mr.developer extension as suggested by Ross.

While doing that I had another question popping up. Which is the best place to specify the dependencies - in the buildout.cfg or in the setup.py of the 'develop' modules? For now I have duplicated the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028765/replicating-reproducing-the-django-development-environment/7038268#comment-8706212), you make your checkout the buildout itself, so you'd place buildout.cfg and bootstrap.py in your project root. That way when someone checks out/clones your project, they just do the bootstrap/buildout dannce and they're up and running.

If you have [multiple checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140321/how-to-structure-a-python-projects-with-shared-sub-apps-using-git-and-buidout-wit/7140483#7140483), then look into [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer).

Comment: thanks, using mr.developer extension, I was able to achieve what I wanted. I will post my buildout.cfg once I can answer to this question. Thanks. :-)